# Icon-based menu that dynamically changes based on permissions

Tags: web-part, permissions, javascript, css

We're trying to create an square grid, icon-based menu that is permission trimmed (certain icons appear based on your specific SP permission group), that dynamically rearranges the icons based on your permissions. Our requirements dictate that we must avoid GAC-deployed solutions, so attempting to alter SPSecurityTrimmedControl to respond to SP Permissions groups (instead of levels) doesn't seem doable. We can achieve the desired hide effect using web part audiencing (we understand this is not true security, but it is sufficient for our needs).

Right now, to achieve the desired arrangement/treatment of icons we are placing each one individually in a web part, applying the audience, and placing all of the webparts in a horizontal web part zone. This method creates the desired behavior of sliding icons over to the left when one is hidden, however, we can't determine a way to limit the the width of the zone and force the icons to wrap to the next line so that they can move fluidly based on what's shown by permission group.

If we are barking up the wrong tree and there's a better idea, or any one has any thoughts on achieving this wrapping action, we'd really appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

List with content query webpart (with custom template) will spit out html to the client side (security trimmed) ! Use jquery to achieve your desired UI and animation.

Comment: A custom xslt template and jquery? Just do it all in a DVWP imo.

Answer (score 0):

Now that you've explained it a bit more, couldn't you create a list with item level permissions based on SharePoint groups? Then you could fetch that data (icon, title, description, etc) with something like jQuery/SPServices or via a DVWP and disply it as needed where it'll be security trimmed automatically?

See a more detailed walkthrough in my blog post, http://pirateeric.sharepointspace.com/blog/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=13

Comment: In addition to the list-backed storage, I would suggest a single control to render all of the appropriate links, not one per function.

Comment: Yes, as with either route, jQuery or DVWP, it's automatically filtered based on the users permissions.

Comment: The item-level permissions list has promise. It would be ideal if the site-owners could manage the permissions and icons (hence why we were ok with audiences)...we'll try that and see if we can make any progress. I'll report back!

Comment: With the list backend they would be able to, they simply change it item level permissions through the UI and add/edit item metadata as necessary.  I'm using this method for a web part driving a category based home page navigation, without security trimming, that will be going live soon.

Comment: @PirateEric and you have a blog post about how you built it that you are just *dying* to share with me, right? ;-D

Comment: Not at the moment but I can get round to it, just twitter DMd you.